# How do i make this good or bad python code work?

Tags: python

How do I make this good or bad python code work? Below is my code:

```
print("how are you today")

good = 1
bad = 2

if "1":
    print("thats good to hear")

if "2":
    print("thats not good")
```

Comment: If you want to get info from the user, you have to ask for it.  `answer = input("How are you today?")`.

Comment: in python 3.10 I think there is switch case.

Comment: You can't change the question like this. It makes the answers as invalid

Answer (score 1):

You're not taking input from the user. You're just printing how are you today. Ask the user to tell how's he/she. Then using if condition, print your msg according to the input. Your code:

```
x=input("How are you today")
if x=="1":
    print("That's good to hear")
else:
    print("That's not good")
```

Answer (score 0):

Two liner in python :)

```
x = input("How are you today")
print("That's good to hear") if int(x) == 1 else print("That's not good")
```

This is just the pythonic way to write `if else` logic in one line.
The code will check if input is `1` then it will execute the first print i.e That's good to hear .
If input is not equal to 1 then else part will run and will print That's not good

Answer (score 0):

```
print("how are you today")
enter = int(input("enter '1' for God, and enter '2' for bad:- "))
    
good = 1 
bad = 2
    
if 1 == enter:
    print("thats good to hear")
    
if 2 == enter: 
    print("thats not good")
```